# T-SQL Procedure Takes too much time but the same query block executed in zero seconds

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I am facing a very unique problem. I have a T-SQL query which give me the daily stock report.
When I am executing this query in SQL Server Management Studio it take zero seconds to execute  but the same query block takes un-identified time when executing through the procedure.

Comment: Have you tried using the WITH (NOLOCK) hint?

Answer (score 2):

There could be many reasons, but I believe `Parameter Sniffing` is the cause here.
There are many ways to handle this problem. But the following two ways are the most common.

1. You can make local copies of input Parameters and use them in your query
2. or Append the `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ...)` clause at the end of your query.

e.g.

Using OPTION OPTIMIZE FOR:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
(
    @Param1 VARCHAR(255),
    @Param2 INT,
    @Param3 BIGINT
)
as
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers
    WHERE  CustomerName = @Param1
        or CustomerId = @Param2
        or CityId = @Param3
    OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@Param1 UNKNOWN, @Param2 UNKNOWN, @Param3 UNKNOWN))
END
```

Using Local Variables:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
(
    @Param1 VARCHAR(255),
    @Param2 INT,
    @Param3 BIGINT
)
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Param1Local VARCHAR(255) = @Param1,
            @Param2Local INT = @Param2,
            @Param3Local BIGINT = @Param3

    SELECT * 
    FROM Customers
    WHERE  CustomerName = @Param1Local
        or CustomerId = @Param2Local
        or CityId = @Param3Local
END
```

Comment: When you use following

Comment: Both of the above ways tell SQL Server to generate a generic execution plan, and not use its own intelligence. Did any of the above methods work for you?

Comment: No, My question was regarding The execution time difference between the Execution of T-SQL query and the Procedure having the same query.

Comment: T-SQL Query takes 1 second for the execution while the same T-SQL query written inside procedure takes 8 minutes for execution.

Comment: @Avtansh, Did you try any of the above methods I suggested for your stored procedure?

Comment: yes but things became the same after 2 or 3 days.